# How to create list of all column names except for the first 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the column names A,B,C,D,E,F,G
I'd like to create a list of all the column names except for the first 3 columns so that column_names would be ['D','E','F','G']

I tried:

```
column_names = list(df[3:])
```

However, I still get all of the column names in that list.

Comment: `df.columns[3:]` ?

Comment: Wow that solved my problem. Thank you so much! I wonder why df[3:] generated a list of the full column names to begin with.

Comment: You want `list(df)[3:]` and not `list(df[3:])`.

Comment: @DeepLearner123 Try `print(df[3:5])` and you'll understand why it didn't do what you expected.

Comment: `list(df.iloc[:, 3:])` would have worked (although arguably less efficient than `df.columns[3:]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
column_names = yourdf.columns[3:].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `columns` attribute of the DataFrame. Here's the correct syntax:

```
column_names = list(df.columns[3:])
```